# Почему есть проблемы с скролингом страницы сайта Youtube

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ситуация такова, я хочу проскролить страницу Youtube (не главную,там где плеер)но постоянно получаю ошибку:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'scrollTop' of undefined at
>   :1:10

Использую Jquery вызов события `scrollTop();` без всякой анимации

```
$(window).scrollTop(100);
$('ytd-app').scrollTop(100);
$('html').scrollTop(100);
$('body').scrollTop(100);
```

но все четно.
Скажите в чем проблема и как это решить, желательно с примерами.

Comment: Эта ошибка возникает когда у искомого элемента нет соответствующего метода(или проперти) Или вообще нет такого элемента.

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'scrollTop' of **undefined** at :1:10

Comment: Но как так? В все четерех случаях одна и таже ошибка но надругих сайтах работает, как так что на странице ютуба не видно тегов Body Html или обєкта window я непойму что там нужно проскролить, какой селектор(тег) выбрать чтобы прокрутить страницу немного вниз

Comment: Не знаю что там с ютубом, но никто не запрещает запустить отладчик встроенный в браузер и найти нужный элемент.

Comment: а можно ли найти нужный тег по скролу в отладчике или както по другому ???

Comment: Нет, нужен просмотр DOM в отладчике браузера, найти элемент(ы) со стилем overflow. Отладчики встроены в большинство браузеров, посмотри в меню. Элемент(или стиль) может быть добавлен динамически, поэтому только так.